# Cross browser compatibility issue of Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8 for png/jpg image used as background of an html element

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, png, jpeg, internet-explorer-6

When I use png/jpg image as background of an element of my html document, it's not compatible with Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8. How can I fix this cross browser compatibility issue ?

Comment: By upgrading your Internet Explorer. Newer versions provide more functionality and better implementations of CSS standards.

Comment: Your comment is very disgusting . First understand the question then answer !! My question is all about cross browser compatibility issue. You understand I think.

Comment: But you provide *no* information **at all**. Stating "it does not work" is not a question. Show your code that does not work.

Comment: Here I mentioned "When I use png/jpg image as background of an element" . From this it can be easily understood. By the way, thanks for you comment. But it's a matter of regret  to give a down vote for this important issue.

Comment: How to show code I don't know the process. There is no buttom for that, I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alhamdulillah ! I have solved my issue.

When I use the background property with the value of rgba colour like

background: url("images/cross.png") no-repeat scroll left center rgba(0,0,0,0,),

the code is not compatible with IE 6,7 and 8. It doesn't matter whether the image is png or jpg.

So, we have to use the property without colour or with hex colour code like

background: url("images/cross.png") no-repeat scroll left center;
 or 
background: url("images/cross.png") no-repeat scroll left center #000;

Then it'll be compatible.

Thanks